# Very slow loop using grep or fgrep on large datasets

Tags: bash, loops, grep

I’m trying to do something pretty simple; grep from a list, an exact match for the string, on the files in a directory:

```
#try grep each line from the files
for i in $(cat /data/datafile); do 
LOOK=$(echo $i);
fgrep -r $LOOK /data/filestosearch >>/data/output.txt
done
```

The file with the matches to grep with has 20 million lines, and the directory has ~600 files, with a total of ~40Million lines
I can see that this is going to be slow but we estimated it will take 7 years. Even if I use 300 cores on our HPC splitting the job by files to search, it looks like it could take over a week.

there are similar questions:

[Loop Running VERY Slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5731275/loop-running-very-slow)
:

[Very slow foreach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12202137/very-slow-foreach-loop)

here and although they are on different platforms, I think possibly if else might help me.
or fgrep which is potentially faster (but seems to be a bit slow as I'm testing it now)
Can anyone see a faster way to do this?
Thank you in advance

Comment: Use `fgrep --word-regexp` unless you need substring-matching. Also try `fgrep --files-with-matches` if you only want to know the matching filenames.

Comment: Since `i` is already a variable, there is no need to spawn a subshell just to assign its value to another variable called `LOOK`.

Comment: As an aside, the needless and inelegant backticks also contribute to the slowdown, though probably no more than a few per cent of the overall processing time. http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html#backticks

Comment: @tripleee , i can't see the backticks, which do you mean?

Comment: Sorry, I was inexactly referring to the `$(command)` subsitutions (the legacy Bourne syntax for this construct used backticks).

Comment: See this post: [Fastest way to find lines of a file from another larger file in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42239179/fastest-way-to-find-lines-of-a-file-from-another-larger-file-in-bash)

Answer (score 5):

sounds like the `-f` flag for `grep` would be suitable here:

```
-f FILE, --file=FILE
    Obtain  patterns  from  FILE,  one  per  line.   The  empty file
    contains zero patterns, and therefore matches nothing.   (-f  is
    specified by POSIX.)
```

so `grep` can already do what your loop is doing, and you can replace the loop with:

```
grep -F -r -f /data/datafile /data/filestosearch >>/data/output.txt
```

Now I'm not sure about the performance of 20 million patterns, but at least you aren't starting 20 million processes this way so it's probably significantly faster.

Comment: sorry I meant to say I was using grep -f first, then I saw something about fgrep being faster, I might edit the original to mention that. I see now from your answer that actually they need to be used in combination > no I'm confused. Looking at my script, I'm re-editing back to how it was. Sorry again

Comment: Yes, `fgrep` means `grep -F`(upper case F), which is slightly faster since it treats patterns as fixed strings and not regular expressions. What I'm proposing is that you also add `-f` (lower case f) to load patterns from a file. This way you will eliminate the overhead of `grep`'s startup

Answer (score 2):

As Martin has already said in his answer, you should use the `-f` option instead of looping. I think it should be faster than looping.

Also, this looks like an excellent use case for [GNU parallel](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/). Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9067042/373151) for usage examples. It looks difficult, but is actually quite easy to set up and run.

Other than that, 40 million lines should not be a very big deal for grep if there was only one string to match. It should be able to do it in a minute or two on any decent machine. I tested that 2 million lines takes 6 s on my laptop. So 40 mil lines should take 2 mins.

The problem is with the fact that there are 20 million strings to be matched. I think it must be running out of memory or something, especially when you run multiple instances of it on different directories. Can you try splitting the input match-list file? Try splitting it into chunks of 100000 words each for example.

**EDIT**: Just tried parallel on my machine. It is amazing. It automatically takes care of splitting the grep on to several cores and several machines.

Comment: Try: parallel -j2 'cat datafile | parallel --pipe grep -F -f - ' ::: files_to_search*

Comment: Or: parallel -n30 -j2 'cat datafile | parallel --pipe grep -F -f - ' ::: files_to_search*

Comment: Thank you for answering, I'm going to try a few of these solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to speed things up:

```
while read i
do
    LOOK=$(echo $i)
    fgrep -r $LOOK /deta/filetosearch >> /data/output.txt
done < /data/datafile
```

When you do that `for i in $(cat /data/datafile)`, you first spawn another process, but that process must cat out all of those lines before running the rest of the script. Plus, there's a good possibility that you'll overload the command line and lose some of the files on the end.

By using q `while read` loop and redirecting the input from `/data/datafile`, you eliminate the need to spawn a shell. Plus, your script will immediately start reading through the `while` loop without first having to cat out the entire `/data/datafile`.

If `$i` are a list of directories, and you are interested in the files underneath, I wonder if `find` might be a bit faster than `fgrep -r`.

while read i
    do
        LOOK=$(echo $i)
        find $i -type f | xargs fgrep $LOOK >> /data/output.txt
    done < /data/datafile

The `xargs` will take the output of find, and run as many files as possible under a single `fgrep`. The `xargs` can be dangerous if file names in those directories contain whitespace or other strange characters. You can try (depending upon the system), something like this:

```
find $i -type f -print0 | xargs --null fgrep $LOOK >> /data/output.txt
```

On the Mac it's

```
find $i -type f -print0 | xargs -0 fgrep $LOOK >> /data/output.txt
```

As others have stated, if you have the GNU version of grep, you can give it the `-f` flag and include your `/data/datafile`. Then, you can completely eliminate the loop.

Another possibility is to switch to Perl or Python which actually will run faster than the shell will, and give you a bit more flexibility.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the detailed explanation this makes it much clearer for me. xargs should work I have no whitespace. Okay i'll try but not with python this time. I've never used python but I think i will try and learn some my perl is even shakier than my bash knowledge but it should be simple enough .

Comment: also I need the line from the file, not the location, so I think find not so useful. thanks

Comment: The `$(echo)` still seems completely superfluous and wasteful.

Comment: Using `find` to run `fgrep` in each file will indeed extract the matching lines, not file names (which is what I imagine you mean with "locations").

Comment: `xargs -0` should work on other platforms too, at least those with GNU `find`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are searching for simple strings (and not regexp) you may want to use `comm`:

```
comm -12 <(sort find_this) <(sort in_this.*) > /data/output.txt
```

It takes up very little memory, whereas `grep -f find_this` can gobble up 100 times the size of 'find_this'.

On a 8 core this takes 100 sec on these files:

```
$ wc find_this; cat in_this.* | wc
3637371   4877980 307366868 find_this
16000000 20000000 1025893685
```

Be sure to have a reasonably new version of `sort`. It should support `--parallel`.

Answer (score 0):

You can write perl/python script, that will do the job for you. It saves all the forks you need to do when you do this with external tools.

Another hint: you can combine strings that you are looking for in one regular expression.
In this case grep will do only one pass for all combined lines.

Example:

Instead of

```
for i in ABC DEF GHI JKL
do
grep $i file >> results
done
```

you can do

```
egrep "ABC|DEF|GHI|JKL" file >> results
```

Comment: hmm, I think it would be a bit to long to put 20M matches in but I could wrap it in a  script I suppose, might try this, thank you for replying